# Rspec failing when attempting to find user in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in my model spec (user_spec.rb). I'm attempting to check that the authentication method works with a valid password, but something is going wrong in the `User.find_by` part of the spec I think since it returns `nil`. I've checked that it responds to :authenticate, :password, and :password_confirmation, which passes (I'll omit that in the code below for the sake of readability).

Here's the failure I'm getting when running the spec:

```
Failures:

  1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password should eq #<User id: 136, fullname: "Sherwood Hickle", email: "jewell.brekke@stokes.net", created_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", updated_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$O5V2X9sZrl/u2T9W25c3Pu/PU6XaIvtZSIB39Efkid6a...">
     Failure/Error: it { should eq found_user.authenticate(user.password) }

       expected: #<User id: 136, fullname: "Sherwood Hickle", email: "jewell.brekke@stokes.net", created_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", updated_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$O5V2X9sZrl/u2T9W25c3Pu/PU6XaIvtZSIB39Efkid6a...">
            got: #<User id: nil, fullname: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -#<User id: 136, fullname: "Sherwood Hickle", email: "jewell.brekke@stokes.net", created_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", updated_at: "2013-11-06 23:04:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$O5V2X9sZrl/u2T9W25c3Pu/PU6XaIvtZSIB39Efkid6a...">
       +#<User id: nil, fullname: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>

     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
    it { should eq found_user.authenticate(user.password) }
  end

  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
end

end
```

And I'm also using FactoryGirl to generate the username and email addresses but I don't think it has anything to do with the failure:

```
require 'faker' 

FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do |u| 
    u.fullname { Faker::Name.name } 
    u.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    u.password { "foobar" }
    u.password_confirmation { "foobar" }
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way the spec is set up.  You're using an implicit subject which, for this spec, will be User.new. That's why you're seeing a User object with all nil attributes.

Your it clauses should read more like

```
it { found_user.authenticate(user.password).should eq user }
```

and

```
it { user_for_invalid_password.should be_nil }
```

which actually test the behavior.

UPDATE:

With the introduction in RSpec 3.x of expect syntax as the preferred syntax, this would now be:

```
it { expect(found_user.authenticate(user.password)).to eq user }
```

and

```
it { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_nil }
```

Comment: Now you would want to use the `expect(...).to` instead of "should".